# Why mysql table id changed to descending order after running a delete query with cron?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a software in which I insert a 1000 phone numbers from a file(Upload a file to insert a data in mysql table). The data is inserted to the table by reading from the file. The code for this :

```
$handle = fopen("images/".$file_name, "r");

if ($handle) {
    $i=1;
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $num=$line;

        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO sms_details (`sms`,`total_mobiles`,`user_id`,`sms_send_date`,`sms_send_time`,`status`,`file_name`,`mobiles`,`sms_count`,`reportname`) VALUES ('".$mobile_txt."','".$count_of_numbers."','".$id."','".$date."','".$date1."','DELIVRD','".$file_name."','".$num."','".$sms_count."','".$reportname."')");

    }

    fclose($handle);
```

Now I need to delete seven days old data from the database automatically so I have set a cron for this purpose. The code to delete 7 days old data is :

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-7 day'));

$qry=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM sms_details WHERE `sms_send_date` < '".$date."'")
or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

This is working fine. But when I try to insert the new records i.e upload a new file with numbers to insert new data, the ID order (which is set to primary key and autoincrement and Order is ASC) automatically changed to Descending Order in mysqli table(phpmyadmin).In other words,the new records comes with descending id .

This is my mysqli table structure

[image: This is my mysqli table structure]

This is a id order before run a cron to delete 7 days old records from table

[image: This is a id order before run a cron to delete 7 days old records from table]

This is a id order after run a cron to delete 7 days old records from table

[image: This is a id order after run a cron to delete 7 days old records from table]

Please suggest me why this occurs and what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: you cannot insert descending. it just depends on how your data is selected

Comment: What do you mean by _"automatically changed to Descending Order"_? Where? In your database admin tool? In a select query? Which order things shows up in is dependent on your SELECT query. If you don't have a `ORDER BY`-clause, you can never be 100% sure in which order you get the results. Add a `ORDER BY id ASC` and the results will always be returned in that order.

Comment: it is automatically changed to descending order when i have upload  a new file after run a cron to delete a 7 days old data.

Comment: In my mysql table ...the next data is insert with descending id

Comment: Do you mean that if you have id 10, the new insert get's id 9?

Comment: it is a backend (mysql table in phpadmin ) error...but why i don't know. In frontend the data is show properly.

Comment: yes Magnus Eriksson

Comment: the next id is 9 ...

Comment: Theres a little drop down for datatables in phpmyadmin on the column name that lets you filter ASC or DESC. nothing to do with insert

Comment: That sounds very strange. Please show us your table schema. (in your question, not in a comment).

Comment: @Mamta please transfer all of your comment details into your question via question edit, then delete all of your commented details -- this puts the full story all in one predictable location.

Comment: Magnus Eriksson Please check my table schema.

Comment: i find that there is no issue with cron...it is a issue in delete query.Actually when i delete any record from the center of table or top of table and new record is insert at the place of deleted record.For example, if i have 10 records in ASC order.i delete record with id 5 and then insert a new record , the new record in insert with id 11 but insert before 6 (i.e at the place of deleted id 5).But when i insert record without run delete query it is insert at the correct location i.e after 10.This is the actual issue which i face.